# node.js: tools/linux-tick-processor v8.log does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, profiling, v8

Does anyone know why "node --prof test.js" not work ?

What I did are followings:

git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git

./configure

make

sudo make install

cd node/deps/v8/

make dependencies

make native

vim test.js

node --prof test.js

tools/linux-tick-processor v8.log

The results are:

Statistical profiling result from v8.log, (0 ticks, 0 unaccounted, 0 excluded).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the official online tool - [Tick processor](http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tools/tick-processor.html) - or you could try

```
npm install tick
```

and then running

```
node-tick-processor
```

in your program.